# Combining array of unequal string characters to forma matix using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a set of string variables from letters A to H assigned to M, N and P as follows:

M = BCD

N = ADFG

P = ADEHG

Using Matlab, I will like to combine MNP as a 3X8 matrix. I want it displayed as shown below:

```
NaN   B     C     D    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

A    NaN   NaN    D    NaN    F     G    NaN   

A    NaN   NaN    D     E    NaN    G     H
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: your variables are Chars? and you want a matrix of Chars and NaNs as result?

Comment: Yes, my variables are chars and i want a matrix of chars. I just want to get a matrix of equal dimensions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you actually have Cell Arrays:

```
M = {'B','C','D'};
N = {'A','D','F','G'};
P =  {'A','D','E','H','G'};

F = unique([M,N,P])
F(~ismember(F(1,:),M)) = {NaN}

>>  NaN    'B'    'C'    'D'    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN

F(~ismember(F(1,:),N)) = {NaN}

>>   'A'    NaN    NaN    'D'    NaN    'F'    'G'    NaN

F(~ismember(F(1,:),P)) = {NaN}

>>   'A'    NaN    NaN    'D'    'E'    NaN    'G'    'H'
```

you can combine the answers using vertcat or simply [;]. Do cell2mat if you want matrix, but I am not sure you can unless you change the Chars to something numeric.